# How to clear contents of all the files using find command

Tags: bash, scripting, regular-expressions

Is there an easy step to clear contents of all  **".log"** file using find command.

Currently i am using "echo -n > filename.log"
i have tried echo -n > /var/application-logs/*.log but it is not working..

is there a better way to clear contents of multiple files?

Comment: What is your exact find command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To clear everything `find /var/application-logs -type f -name "*.log"` finds, use this:

```
find /var/application-logs -type f -name "*.log" -exec tee {} \; </dev/null
```

If your version of find supports it, use `+` instead of `\;` to use a single run of tee for all of the files.  Alternately, if a shell glob is sufficient:

```
tee /var/application-logs/*.log </dev/null
```

Comment: POSIX stipulates that find supports {} +; I don't know of any that don't.

Comment: @adaptr: I could've sworn I saw one that didn't support `+` recently, but maybe I'm imagining it. You're right, though, it is in [the Posix standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html).

Comment: Thanks a ton ! This saved me an hour worth of my time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop your logs from growing, use [`logrotate`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate). You should not be blindly wiping logs just because they are full. There are good [HOWTOs](http://linuxers.org/howto/howto-use-logrotate-manage-log-files) available for many different distros.

Alternatively, consider using a syslog server such as `rsyslog` or `syslog-ng`.

Comment: i am using logrotate,,,this is a special case where i want to perform benchmark on application,which i need to monitor logs.So it will be convinient to remove all logs relating to that..

Comment: @hariharan It would be worth updating your original question with this information so that your intent is clear.

Comment: can u please check now...i have changed log location

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar situation where I had to delete Docker Container Logs with ".log" extension using a command or a shell script (it was scenario-specific)

Here's the script

```
#!/bin/bash

#SHELL SCRIPT TO DELETE THE CONTENT OF THE DOCKER CONTAINER LOG FILES

#Declaring Array
file_list=()

#While loop to read log file name
 while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file ; do
     file_list=("${file_list[@]}" "$file")
 done < <(find /var/lib/docker/containers/ -type f -name "*.log" -print0)

#Printing log file names
 echo "${file_list[@]}"

#Deleting the content of the log files
 for f in "${file_list[@]}";do
    if [ -f $f ]
    then
      : > "$f"
    fi
 done
```

### Explanation of Bash Elements

---

`file_list=()` is an array containing the results of `find /var/lib/docker/containers/ -type f -name "*.log"`

While loop is used to read the log file names

```
while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file ; do
     file_list=("${file_list[@]}" "$file")
 done < <(find /var/lib/docker/containers/ -type f -name "*.log" -print0)
```

where the `find` subprocess is used by the `while` command via `<`

and `IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file` is the while condition

which reads one line of input from the `find` command.

`echo "${file_list[@]}"` is to print the file name stored in the array.

```
for f in "${file_list[@]}";do
    if [ -f $f ]
    then
      : > "$f"
    fi
 done
```

In the above for-(if)-loop snippet, the loop reads each file from the array `${file_list[@]}` and the `if` statement `then` clears the content of the file using `: > "$f"`

Comment: This is exactly the type of answer we love to see on Stack Exchange.